# Custom tooltips for tree with multiple columns. <org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree>

Tags: java, eclipse, event-handling

I am using a [`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Tree.html) object with 2 columns. I want to show different tooltips for the columns.

Using the [`event`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event.html) object, we can find the [`TreeItem`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TreeItem.html) element, but how to tell which of the columns
were Hovered?

```
public void toolTipShown(Event event) {
    Tree tree = (Tree) event.widget;
    TreeItem item = tree.getItem(new Point(event.x, event.y));
    //How do I tell which of the Columns were Hovered?
}
```